# Angular ng-hide'ing is too fast for animation

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, animation

Angular 1.2 with the animate.css from http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/

My animations are for simple `ng-show="somevalue"`. I have animations working for the ng-show, it nicely fades in. But when the element goes to be hidden, it disappears **before** the **fadeout** animation can display.

I've tried, `.fader.ng-hide-add-active`, `.fader.ng-hide-add` etc. But the animation just doesn't show. The element disappears instantly.

```
.fader.ng-hide-remove {
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

.fader.ng-hide-add-active {
    -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    -o-animation: fadeOut 1s;
    animation: fadeOut 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename it to `.fader.ng-hide-add` and add `display: block !important;`:

```
.fader.ng-hide-add {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 1s;
  -o-animation: fadeOut 1s;
  animation: fadeOut 1s;
  display: block !important;
}
```

This is needed to override the default ng-hide style of `display: none`.

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/oUVa7OFddIKIayx6c4aU?p=preview